# PHP Namespace - Parent Class variables not passing correctly to Child Class

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to implement namespaces into a plugin I'm developing for WordPress and I'm running into an issue that seems quite strange. The parent variables are available in the child `__construct` method but not any other method within the child class.

I have a Parent Class - `class.db.php`

Which handles creating and deleting the tables (activating and deactivating the plugin ) and storing some variables like table names etc.

I then have a Child Class - `class.db.users.php`

that extends off the parent class above and handles all the CRUD methods for the User table.

Parent Class - `class.db.php`

```
<?php
namespace PUWP\DB\Functions;

class PU_dbFunctions{

    public $wpdb;
    public $collate;
    public $userTable;

    function __construct(){
        global $wpdb;
        $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
        $this->collate = $this->wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        $this->userTable = $this->wpdb->prefix.'pu_users';
    }
}
?>
```

Child Class - `class.db.users.php`

```
<?php

namespace PUWP\DB\Functions\Users;

DBFunctions(); // Temporary Function to include DB file above.

use PUWP\DB\Functions\PU_dbFunctions as PUWPDB;

class PU_dbUsers extends PUWPDB {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        var_dump( $this->wpdb );
        // returns as expected
    }
    public function returnUserByEmail( $email ){
        var_dump( $this->wpdb );
        var_dump( $this->userTable );
        // both return null
        return $this->wpdb->get_results( $this->wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `{$this->userTable}` WHERE `email`= %s", $email ), OBJECT );
    }
}
?>
```

I've tried removing the child `__construct` method together which didn't seem to work.

What have I done wrong? Everything was working fine till I started adding in the namespaces. Any help would be much appreciated.

### EDIT

Calling from:

I have another 2 classes - One for Ajax Calls (which loads the next User Class ) and one for User Interactions / Formatting returned results from DB (login, auth check, etc.)

`class.user.php`

```
DBUserFunctions();

use PUWP\DB\Functions\Users\PU_dbUsers as DBUsers;
use DateTime;
class PU_User extends DBUsers {
    // Class Methods
    public function login( $email , $password ){

        $user = $this->returnUserByEmail( $email );
        //rest of login code if user is returned
    }
    public function get_UserByEmail( $email ){

        $user = $this->returnUserByEmail( $id ); 
        if( is_array( $user ) && ! empty( $user ) ){
            $user = $this->formatUser( $user[0] );
            return $user;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

`class.ajax.php`

```
<?php
// User Database is included before this file is included in the plugin.
namespace PUWP\Ajax;
use PUWP\Users\PU_User as PUWPUSERS;

class Ajax_Handler{

    private $pu_settings;
    public $PUusers;

    function __construct(){

        $this->PUusers = new PUWPUSERS;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this ~ https://3v4l.org/00MM8. Where are you creating an instance of `\PUWP\DB\Functions\PU_dbFunctions\PU_dbUsers`? Where are you calling the `returnUserByEmail()` method?

Comment: I've added how its included into the question. Have I extended to far with the classes? Maybe I should include the DB into DBusers and Extend Users from DBUsers.

Comment: I managed to get it working by adding: `parent::__construct();` into the `class.users.php` method `__construct`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by adding: parent::__construct(); into the class.users.php method __construct